# C++ eror:invalid conversation from 'const char*' to 'int'

Tags: c++

I am a beginner.  I want use this `MoveSkill` class with a `Crusader` object, but I can't do it.

161

```
class MoveSkill : public Skill {
public:
    int step;   // kaç adım yer değişecek, - ise geriye + ise ileriye
    MoveSkill(int step);

public:
    virtual void Use(std::vector<Unit*> units, int userIndex, int onUsing);
};
```

596

```
MoveSkill::MoveSkill(int step) : Skill(std::vector<int>(), std::vector<int>(), "") {
    this->step = step;
}
```

894

```
Crusader::Crusader(std::string name) : Hero(33, 5, 0, 1, 0, 3, 6, 12, 67, 40, name) {
    smite = new Smite("Smite");
    stunningBlow = new Stunning_Blow("Stunning Blow");
    holyLance = new Holy_Lance("Holy Lance");
    bulwark = new Bulwark_Of_Faith("Bulwark Of Faith");
    moveskill= new MoveSkill("Move skill");
    skills.push_back(smite);
    skills.push_back(stunningBlow);
    skills.push_back(((AttackSkill*)holyLance));
    skills.push_back(bulwark);
    skills.push_back(moveskill);
}
```

Build message:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Users\emred\Desktop\project.cpp||In constructor 'Crusader::Crusader(std::__cxx11::string)':|
C:\Users\emred\Desktop\project.cpp|894|error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\emred\Desktop\project.cpp|596|note:   initializing argument 1 of 'MoveSkill::MoveSkill(int)'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your compiler says that you declared the constructor to take an `int` but you gave it a string. Which one is it? In addition, `*moveskill = ...` looks suspiciously like dereferencing an uninitialized pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @chris I think the extra `*` on that line are just to help point out which line is failing to compile. See the `*` after the `;` as well? They are probably not in the OP's actual code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks, I missed the trailing one.

Comment: exactly remy thank you

Answer (score 2):

On this statement:

```
moveskill= new MoveSkill("Move skill");
```

The `MoveSkill()` constructor expects an `int` as input, but you are giving it a string literal instead (in this case, a `const char[11]`).  So, either give it what it wants, eg:

```
moveskill= new MoveSkill(12345);
```

Or else you will have to change the `MoveSkill` constructor to take a `std::string` instead of an `int`.